# Django Debug Toolbar Won't Hide on Chrome

Tags: django, google-chrome, django-debug-toolbar

Clicking on Hide on the Django debug toolbar (version 1.10.1) does not work on my Google Chrome (Version 69.0.3497.100). I'm using Django 1.11.15 and I can confirm that the Hide does indeed work on Firefox.

The following is output by the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: djdt is not defined at toolbar.js:305

Line 305 being:

`})(djdt.jQuery, djdt);`

Anyone have suggestions on how to fix this or provide a possible workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toolbar.js` file does not contain `})(djdt.jQuery, djdt);` in [version 1.10.1](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/blob/1.10.1/debug_toolbar/static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js). It sounds like your browser may have cached an old version of `toolbar.js`.

You may have to run `collectstatic` To update your static files with the new version.